# Merge x axis and legend of multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the following R code I generated multiple plots onto one plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

Adata=nt.df[( nt.df$Species=='Human' | nt.df$Species=='Arabidopsis' )& nt.df$Nucleotide=='A',]
Cdata=nt.df[( nt.df$Species=='Human' | nt.df$Species=='Arabidopsis' )& nt.df$Nucleotide=='C',]
Gdata=nt.df[( nt.df$Species=='Human' | nt.df$Species=='Arabidopsis' )& nt.df$Nucleotide=='G',]
Udata=nt.df[( nt.df$Species=='Human' | nt.df$Species=='Arabidopsis' )& nt.df$Nucleotide=='U',]
# Grouped
Aplot <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=Species, y=Percent, x=Position)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

Cplot <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=Species, y=Percent, x=Position)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

Gplot <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=Species, y=Percent, x=Position)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

Uplot <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=Species, y=Percent, x=Position)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")


grid.arrange(Aplot,Cplot,Gplot,Uplot,ncol=1)
```

[image]

How can I merge the x axis label, the y axis labels, and the `Species` legend into 1 for the entire figure?

Also, would it make more sense to have the Position tick marks labeled for the entire figure or for each figure?

Comment: This [R Bloggers Post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/another-rule-of-three-this-one-in-statistics/)   has an example of what you want.  It is not the point of the post,  but you should be able to follow the code to see how to get this.

Comment: You should consider merging the data to a single data frame and use `facet_wrap()`, which will also merge your axis ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(dplyr) 
require(ggplot2)

nt.df %>% 
     filter(Species %in% c('Human', 'Arabidopsis')) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(fill = Species, y = Percent, x = Position)) +
     geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
     facet_wrap(. ~ Nucleotide)
```

Since the data wasn't posted I couldn't test it, but this should work. Let me know if you get an error. If you've never used piping before (`%>%`), it's a popular way to make code more readable and concise. Basically it makes whatever is to the left the first arg in the function to the right. In this case, data is the first arg in `ggplot()` so the filtered dataset goes into `ggplot()`

Comment: I actually use RMarkdown, not Jupyter so I don't have any suggestions. Did this answer your question though?

Comment: I did spend some time helping you so I'd appreciate an answer upvote or best answer if this did help you